# OrbitControl.js with smoother zooming and rotating?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

My demo is up [here](http://globatum.com/testing/)

You'll notice the zooming is quite choppy. The rotating is very static.
I'm looking to achieve similar results to [Google's WebGL Globe.](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/globe/)

At first I was using the standard OrbitControl.js file

but I wasn't liking the overall feel of it. So I started using [this](https://gist.github.com/paulkaplan/5770247) one which 
includes some part about momentum and such.

I've tried embedding it but I had little luck.

```
// CONTROLS

                  cameraControls = new THREE.OrbitAndPanControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
                  cameraControls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
                                      cameraControls.maxDistance = 610;
                                      cameraControls.minDistance = 210;
                                      cameraControls.userRotateSpeed = 500;
                                      cameraControls.momentumDampingFactor = 8;
                                      cameraControls.momentumScalingFactor = 0.005;
                              cameraControls.getMouseProjectionOnBall2 = cameraControls.getMouseProjectionOnBall;

 cameraControls.getMouseProjectionOnBall = function(x, y){ return cameraControls.getMouseProjectionOnBall2.call(cameraControls, x, cameraControls.screen.height/2);}
```

Playing around with the numbers on the momentum lines hasn't helped much.
Is there something I'm not doing right or is this just a limitation of the script?
Are there any other scripts out there with a smoother feel than OrbitConrol.js?

Note: Changing the user rotating speed parameter does nothing.
Note2: I am basically trying to build [this](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Halo.html)
Notice how smooth the rotating is. I don't want to use trackballcontrol.js because it doesn't limit the rotating angle like orbitcontrol.js

Comment: You can see whole code for the demo on the last link. It uses Trackball Controls instead of Orbit. If you have access to the whole code, what's the problem then?

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm i'm trying to learn everything step by step. It's hard to describe with words but the range of rotation for Trackball Control is unfavorable. I need to keep the top-side facing up.